# Let $a$ be a positive integer. Prove: if $\sqrt a ∈ \mathbb Q,$ then $\sqrt a ∈ \mathbb N.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a$ be a positive integer. Prove that if
>   $\sqrt a ∈ \mathbb Q,$ then $\sqrt a ∈ \mathbb N.$

I know this has something to do with primes, but I'm having a hard time getting started.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\sqrt a=p/q,$ where $p,q\in\mathbb Z.$ Then $$aq^2=p^2$$ and the Unique Factorization Theorem implies that the exponent of every prime factor of $a$ must be even, which means that $a$ is a perfect square and hence..

Comment: This is a great proof. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You don't need to use primes. There is a *very* elementary proof.

Since $x$ is rational, there exist integers $n>0$ such that $nx$ is an integer. Let $q$ be the smallest of these, and  denote $y=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the decimal part of $x$.

Prove $q'=qy$ is an integer and observe that  $q'x$ is an integer. Deduce $y=0$.

Comment: Well, that's relative because how do you prove the existence of $\lfloor x\rfloor$?

Comment: You forget $x$ is a fraction… Any fraction is between two integers.

Comment: You are right!, I was thinking on the general case (when $x$ is not necessarily rational)

Comment: That's another problem. There you need the archimedean property.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{a} = \frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{N}^*$ are relatively prime integers. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $q > 1$. Notice that we have the following equality:

$$ a q^2 = p^2. $$

However if we pick a prime factor of $q$ say $s \mid q$, then $s \mid aq^2$ yet $s \nmid p^2$. Contradiction.

**Remark**:

We can prove by this way that for a positive integer $a$ and an integer $m > 1$, if $\sqrt[m]{a} \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt[m]{a} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{a}=\frac35\in\Bbb Q$ and so how is $\sqrt a=\frac35\in\Bbb N$?